# Recommendations for 5.1 Surround Headphones?

Tags: surround-sound, headphones

Are there any good relatively-flat surround headphones out there?

I started doing research but came across alot of gaming headsets which usually are never flat. I've actually never tried surround headphones and am somewhat suspicious of the technology anyway. Perhaps it's a sign that no "audio" companies seem to make surround headphones. I certainly don't want any of the faux surround stuff from 2 drivers. I'm looking for headsets with multiple drivers in each ear.

These would be used for playing games and to reference other games. I wouldn't try to mix on them.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you use the term "faux" to characterize surround sound using two drivers, as it is actually a big research subject not only by academics but also by audio companies such as DTS. Have a listen to the Z+ Music app, by DTS, which was developed using a new technology they call Headphone X. It's far from perfect, but it sounds promising. Some researchers are trying something like binaural synthesis of 5.1 streams using HRTFs and head-tracking to adapt the HRTFs to the position of the head in real time.
Sorry for not being that helpful, just sharing some thoughts.

Comment: Yeah just a bad taste left in my mouth from previous exposure to some surround things like that. I meant that in regard to headphones and the usual over-hyped marketing promises of 11.2 surround out of 2 drivers and that kinda stuff.  

Comment: Hmm that Headphone X stuff sounds interesting. Turtle Beach will be the first company to use that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

featured in this month's **Sound On Sound** :
*a rather high end approach...*

http://smyth-research.com/

Comment: or the beyer-dynamic headzone stuff. wow didn't know that stuff existed.

Comment: I tried these out once, very cool technology and surprisingly convincing surround field for headphones.